# Problem authenticating in a Chrome extension using a G Suite account

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-workspace

I've created a Chrome extension which requires users to connect with their Google accounts. It uses the standard OAuth login as instructed in the Chrome API docs.
The problem is that when trying to test it with my G suite account, I'm shown a popup with the G Suite admin console page, instead of the expected standard Google OAuth page. The correct Google OAuth page is shown when used with a regular Gmail account, or even with another G suite account, I use at work. I'm not sure what the problem is with this specific G Suite account.

[image]

To give more context, I'm using the following code to request the user's access token:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, (token) => {
  console.log(token);
});
```

Obviously, I've set up everything needed for this to work, including adding the `oauth2` with the `client_id` and `scopes` to the `manifest.json` file.
I've also added the `identity` permission to the `manifest.json` file and made sure the extension's `key` is the same as the one used after uploading the extension to the Chrome Web store.

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my G Suite account configuration, but don't have any clue what it could be. Any thoughts?

**Update October 11, 2018:**
This issue seems to be fixed on Google's end.

Comment: Have you checked this blogpost about pushing chrome extension to users: admin console tutorial? - https://blog.goguardian.com/tech/push-chrome-extension

Comment: Recently, we are facing the same issue for GSuite admin accounts. Please help us. @google

Comment: @pavankumar interesting. I never thought it had to do with the admin account, but you're pointing me at an interesting direction.

Comment: @eshaham for non-admin accounts we are not facing any issue

Comment: @pavankumar seems to be fixed for now

Comment: @eshaham yes it is fixed now.